# Removing title bar changes display of ProgressDialog

Tags: android

In my android app, which is just a webview displaying a responsive web site, I want to remove the title bar so I add this to the application section of the manifest XML.

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

The problem is, I get two totally different `ProgressDialog` UI treatments. The one with the title bar is much nicer so I would like to keep it, but I don't want a title bar.

I believe this relates to the theme. I want to keep the theme, just not the title bar... at least I think. How do I keep the nicer styling, and hide the title bar instantly (not programmatically once the activity starts, that shows the title bar briefly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Theme.NoTitleBar` comes from pre-Honeycomb era, so it shows a pre-Honeycomb dialog.

If your app is API 11 or up you can simply switch by the `Holo` version of it (I honestly don't remember the name).

Or to support both older and newer device you'll have to use this type of approach [Different Theme for different Android SDK versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140085/different-theme-for-different-android-sdk-versions) to apply `Theme.NoTitleBar` to old devices and its `holo` counterpart for newer devices.

happy coding.