# Android layout editor standard 3.0

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an app for android 2.1 and I'd like to create a special layout for tablets with Android 3.0 standard. Can the styling be automatically changed in layout editor, so that I can just drag and drop a 3.0-like button, etc. ? Otherwise, is there any other smart way to change the layout style for Android 3.0?

Comment: Doesn't changing the theme in the layout editor suffice? It's one of the dropdown lists (or perhaps better said in Android terminology: `Spinner`) at the upper right corner in the editor - directly below the one for platform selection. It'll only affect the preview and does nothing to your actual (re)source files.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of these post:

[Program different layouts for different versions in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8908508/program-different-layouts-for-different-versions-in-android)

[Adapt layout to Android platform or API level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536079/adapt-layout-to-android-platform-or-api-level)

Otherwise, you may compile different APKs for different platform versions:

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Comment: But still, I don't know how to get 3.0 styled controls in my designer.

Comment: Try on the emulator. Hope that the system handles that by default.